# C# Winforms datagridview cell validation

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datagridview

I have a datagridview with 3 columns: Guid(invisible), checkbox column and string column.

I need to validate what user entered into string column.
Possible cases:

1) Dont allow to enter duplicate record

2) Dont allow to enter empty record

Need to keep in mind: new row or editing row. For example if empty string for new row and user leaves it - i must just cancel this new row.

But the problem is with checkbox column. When i check that checkbox and leave it (text column is empty) - i unable to validate that. So this is the bottleneck of my code

```
 private void dgvKeywords_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex != 2)
            return;

        string keyWord = e.FormattedValue == null ? string.Empty : e.FormattedValue.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyWord))
            if (!dgvKeywords.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Keyword cannot be empty", "Keyword processing", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                return;
            }

        var list = bsCustomerLanguageKeywords.DataSource as List<CustomerLanguageKeyword>;
        if (list == null)
            throw new Exception("Unexpected type in the keywords grid");

        var separatedList = list.Where((t, i) => i != bsCustomerLanguageKeywords.Position).ToList();

        bool nonUnique = separatedList.Count(x => x.Word != null && x.Word.ToLower() == keyWord.ToLower()) > 0;
        if (nonUnique)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Keyword must be unique", "Keyword processing", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is the best practice ( I am pretty sure it isn't) but what I did was to create a method to validate what I needed to be validated and placed it on several events : UserAddedRow, Focus Leave and Focus RowLeave. Now, you could debug this and see which one of these 3 events fires up first and matches your situation the best and leave it just one (or perhaps max 2). But in my case I had to do this in a rush and never came back to it again :). Good luck and let me know which one did the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the row and column index passed to you in your DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs parameter to get the DataGridViewCell at your location, then depending on what would work best for you, you can access the cell's `Value` property or check to see if the cell is a check box cell and perform some special case logic.